# JSS react app quick start disconnected mode gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sitecore' of null"

Tags: jss

Newly created `JSS app` when started in the disconnected mode as below, tries to consume layout service and fails to load the page

[image]

[image]

what could be causing this. tried creating fresh app multiple times, but the same issue occurs.

tried another fresh app this morning below is the error.

[image]

Comment: Please check your JSS version and Sitecore compatibility. Also, its not required but can you try setting up the API KEY , follow the jss docs for information on that.

Comment: @AbhayDhar - i just want to run the app in disconnected mode for now. I believe Sitecore is not required to run app in disconnected mode.

Comment: what is your jss version ?

Comment: it is version 12.0.0

Comment: for the second screenshot , please check if any errors are there during app creation. This looks like if you are behind corporate proxy/firewall , you need to set up npm with proxy and username/pswd information

Comment: In my case I downloaded TCPViewer, find the

Answer (score 1):

From the first error screenshot, issue is more look like of the **firewall** or **port related issue**.

JSS is somehow unable to connect on **localhost:3042** which is a proxy server (act as Sitecore server in disconnected mode). Please check if this port is already in use or whether any firewall rules are getting applied.